# Oracle SQL Query TO return rows from a table matching two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table "Employees":

```
E_ID    E_Name                E_Salary   Grade
01      Hansen, Ola           15,000     HC_1
02      Svendson, Tove        15,000     HC_2
03      Svendson, Stephen     32,000     HC_9
04      Pettersen, Kari       21,000     HC_1
05      Sachin, Tendulkar     21,000     HC_2
06      Brian, Lara           19,000     HC_3
```

I need to return the Employees Salary that have both HC_1 and HC_2 grades. Can someone help me forming the query for this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: None of the 6 sample rows that you posted would appear to be returned based on the logic you specified.  No employee appears to have both ah `HC_1` and an `HC_2` salary grade.  Do you really want an empty result set?  It would generally make much more sense if your sample data set included at least one row that you wanted to be returned.  Or am I misunderstanding the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: Please just put a sample of the display that you need.

Comment: Hello Cave, Thank you for your time. Yes. I see that my question itself is wrong here. I apologize for that. Actually I want the salary that have both HC_1 and HC_2 grades. Employee name doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want ...

```
 Select   e_salary
 from     employees
 where    grade in ('HC_1','HC_2')
 group by e_salary
 having   count(distinct grade) = 2
```